# Error trying to install albopictus package through pip

Tags: python, c++, pip, installation

I am having trouble installing a package to my conda virtual environment through pip (not available through conda unfortunately) and I don't understand what is going wrong here, so I would greatly appreciate any help please! I'm trying to install the albopictus package through

`pip install albopictus`

but it fails with the following output:

```
Collecting albopictus
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/5c/873ef51ecde98a70eed4e1ac55f68d62d908a2116a2165a90ddcb7d1d06a/albopictus-1.12.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from albopictus) (1.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from albopictus) (1.3.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: albopictus
  Building wheel for albopictus (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-1yizpvoq --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/
  Complete output (94 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/readModel
  copying src/albopictus/readModel/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/readModel
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/plotPos
  copying src/albopictus/plotPos/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/plotPos
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/accessory
  copying src/albopictus/accessory/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/accessory
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/population
  copying src/albopictus/population/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/population
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/dataSurv
  copying src/albopictus/dataSurv/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/dataSurv
  running egg_info
  writing src/albopictus.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/albopictus.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/albopictus.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/albopictus.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/albopictus.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'src/albopictus.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/albopictus/gamma.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/gamma.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/incubator.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/incubator.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/incubator03.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/incubator03.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus08.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus08b.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus13.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus18.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelCulex.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelStochAaegypti.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelStochAalbopictus.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelStochCHIKV.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/modelStochSand.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/ran_gen.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/ran_gen.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/spop.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/spop.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/spop01.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/spop01.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  copying src/albopictus/uthash.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/climate.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/posterior.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/prior03.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/prior08.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/prior13.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/prior18.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/priorAeae.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  copying src/albopictus/data/priorSand.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_F4_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d1_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d2_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d3_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d4_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_gtc_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_n23_dev.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_n23_surv.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_n23_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p0_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p1_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p2_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p3_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_tbm_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
  running build_ext
  building 'albopictus.modelAalbopictus03' extension
  Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
  Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
  C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus
  compile options: '-I/usr/local/include -I/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/include/python3.7m -c'
  gcc: src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.c
  gcc: src/albopictus/incubator03.c
  gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -L/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
  /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
  /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
  /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -L/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for albopictus
  Running setup.py clean for albopictus
Failed to build albopictus
Installing collected packages: albopictus
    Running setup.py install for albopictus ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-irr1xezd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/
    Complete output (94 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/readModel
    copying src/albopictus/readModel/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/readModel
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/plotPos
    copying src/albopictus/plotPos/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/plotPos
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/accessory
    copying src/albopictus/accessory/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/accessory
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/population
    copying src/albopictus/population/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/population
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/dataSurv
    copying src/albopictus/dataSurv/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/dataSurv
    running egg_info
    writing src/albopictus.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/albopictus.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src/albopictus.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/albopictus.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/albopictus.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'src/albopictus.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying src/albopictus/gamma.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/gamma.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/incubator.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/incubator.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/incubator03.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/incubator03.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus08.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus08b.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus13.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus18.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelCulex.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelStochAaegypti.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelStochAalbopictus.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelStochCHIKV.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/modelStochSand.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/ran_gen.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/ran_gen.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/spop.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/spop.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/spop01.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/spop01.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    copying src/albopictus/uthash.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/climate.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/posterior.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/prior03.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/prior08.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/prior13.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/prior18.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/priorAeae.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    copying src/albopictus/data/priorSand.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/data
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_F4_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d1_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d2_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d3_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_d4_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_gtc_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_n23_dev.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_n23_surv.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_n23_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p0_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p1_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p2_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_p3_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    copying src/albopictus/setPrior/data/albopictus_tbm_temp.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/setPrior/data
    running build_ext
    building 'albopictus.modelAalbopictus03' extension
    Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
    Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus
    compile options: '-I/usr/local/include -I/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/include/python3.7m -c'
    gcc: src/albopictus/incubator03.c
    gcc: src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.c
    gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -L/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -L/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e95z7v3l/albopictus/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-irr1xezd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

As I understand it, there's something wrong with compiling with gcc? I'm not familiar with C++ compilers unfortunately, so I would very much appreciate any insights from you guys. I'm getting this error on my Manjaro installation if that makes any difference.

UPDATE:
I've tried modifying the setup.py as suggested by miszcz2137 and running

`python setup.py install`

but I now get the following error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing src/albopictus.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/albopictus.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src/albopictus.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to src/albopictus.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src/albopictus.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src/albopictus.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'albopictus.modelAalbopictus03' extension
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
Make sure that Python modules winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

compile options: '-I/usr/local/include -I/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/include/python3.7m -c'
extra options: '-fPIC'
gcc: src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.c
gcc: src/albopictus/incubator03.c
gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -L/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat -L/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/pantelis/miniconda3/envs/virtual_env/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/incubator03.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lstdc++ -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you share the logs as in the last line says?

Comment: where can I find the logs? The location /tmp/pip-record-irr1xezd/install-record.txt does not exist

Comment: Maybe rerun with this `pip install albopictus --log LOG_FILE`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BgE-IXjHk8uuTrmyRxAzrNEqJL4-eYpJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try to download file from link in line 22, unpack then modify `setup.py` with 
`Extension("albopictus.modelAalbopictus03", ["src/albopictus/incubator03.c", "src/albopictus/modelAalbopictus03.c"], extra_compile_args = ["-fPIC"]),`
 in line about 98 (first `Extension` in `ext_modules`)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for taking the time to look into this. I've tried what you suggested, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've update the initial topic with the error I'm getting.

Comment: Hmm, I think there was mistake on my part and the fix does nothing. Sorry for that.

Comment: Could you try this? https://pastebin.com/UkE0nETK
This compiles two needed object files and then tries to compile shared object file. P.S. Be wary of code snippets pasted from internet.

Comment: I get his when I run that snippet '''envs/virtual_env/compiler_compat/ld: incubator03.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info''' and incubator03.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similar issues:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501516/collect2-error-while-installing-yay-for-arch-linux
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242682

So firstly I would suggest updating binutils:

```
$ pacman -Sy binutils
```

if not then downgrade it according to second link.

Comment: Downgrading binutils solved the problem, thank you very much!! Thank you for your time and effort, greatly appreciated!